# Error when enabling Cockpit Project on Debian 12 Bookworm

Tags: debian, linux-server

I installed cockpit and saw the status not active and not enabled. First I started the service. It was successful. I was able to access the web-console. But when I try to enable for startup on boot. I get this message.

```bash
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

How to correct this... I am just testing this on VirtualBox configured with NAT and Host Only Network.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/startup.html#startup-boot) might help!!!

Here's a quick rundown:

This may caused the problem because cockpit is a socket service and you tried to enable it as a demon service this caused the error. Just run the command:

`$ sudo systemctl enable cockpit.socket`

and see if the problem still persists.